# Share files using Wifi Direct virtual adapter in C#

Tags: c#, networking, wifi-direct

I am creating a app/software to share files from one pc to other pc, By using wifi direct virtual adapter the transfer is high and time getting very less. But I cannot access that adapter using C#.

I want the code to access the Wi-Fi direct adapter and scan the nearby devices, also send and receive the files in pc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.